KDE: Hide notfication content but not the pop-up itself
Is there a way to hide the content of a notification pop-up in KDE from showing (even if for specific applications)? I'd prefer if the notification pop-up is there but the content not shown for the sake of privacy.
I know there is a DND option but I need to know of the notifications.
